# Does this operation similar to a convolution have a name?

Tags: number-theory

Using four consecutive integers the operations are

- (a) 4*(4+5+6+7) + 5*(4+5+6) + 6*(4+5) + 7*4=245
- (b) 4*(4+5+6+7) + 5*(5+6+7) + 6*(6+7) + 7*7=305
- (c) 7*(4+5+6+7) + 6*(5+6+7) + 5*(6+7) + 4*7=355.

The 2nd one (b) is similar to Stirling 2.  Has anyone seen these operations in action?

Comment: No, certainly not, nor do I see any similarity with convolution. I see some arbitrary operations with consecutive integers. Stirling might sue you.

Comment: A convolution produces a sequence; treat this as a series and find the

Comment: sum.  That's the origin of these numbers.